# angular google maps is not loading and doesnt post dynamically to the web service

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, angular-google-maps

I have 2 questions related to Angular Google maps (AGM)

Source for the maps: 
https://angular-maps.com/

When i put the code of AGM inside empty HTML page (the component page)

It works but when i put it inside HTML template it doesn't show, autocomplete is working but map is not showing

Component HTML

```
<fieldset>
          <div style="text-align: center;">
            <p style="font-size: 24px">Enter your address</p>
          </div>

            <!--angular 4 maps-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <input placeholder="search for location" 
autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="on" spellcheck="off" 
type="text" 
class="form-control" #search [formControl]="searchControl">

            </div>

            <agm-map style="height: 300px;"
 [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" 
 [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom" [gestureHandling]="cooperative">
              <agm-marker [markerDraggable]="true" 
 (dragEnd)="markerMoved($event)" [latitude]="latitude" 
 [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>

            </agm-map>

            <!--angular 4 maps-->

          <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-
 button-previous" value="Previous"/>
          <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" 
value="Next"/>
        </fieldset>
```

Component TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpClientModule } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import { AgmCoreModule, MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { ElementRef, NgModule, NgZone, ViewChild } from 
'@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from 
"@angular/forms";
import { AgmMap } from '@agm/core';



declare const google: any;

@Component({
selector: 'app-add-school',
templateUrl: './add-school.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./add-school.component.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AddSchoolComponent implements OnInit {
public latitude: number;
public longitude: number;
public searchControl: FormControl;
public zoom: number;

@ViewChild("search")
public searchElementRef: ElementRef;
@ViewChild(AgmMap)
public agmMap: AgmMap;
name: any[];
logo: any[];
vision: any[];
mission: any[];
address: any[];
emails: any[] = [];
numbers: any[] = [];
school_id: any[];
district_id: number[] = [];
numbertitle: number;
number: number;
private url = 
'https://crm.easyschools.org/api/en/schools/create/create';
countries: any[] = []; // Blank Array not blank object
cities: any[] = []; // Blank Array not blank object
districts: any[] = []; // Blank Array not blank object
imageFile: any;
schoolyears: any[] = [];
start_date: string;
end_date: string;
name_en: any[] = [];
id: number[] = [];
type_id: number[] = [];

constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private mapsAPILoader: 
MapsAPILoader, private ngZone: NgZone) { 
this.getMyBlog();
this.educationType();
}
ngOnInit() {
// this.agmMap.triggerResize();

 // set google maps defaults
this.zoom = 17;
this.latitude = 1500;
this.longitude = 98.5795;

 // create search FormControl
this.searchControl = new FormControl();

 // set current position
this.setCurrentPosition();

 // load Places Autocomplete
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
  let autocomplete = new 
google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
    types: ["address"]
  });
  autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
       // get the place result
      let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = 
autocomplete.getPlace();

       // verify result
      if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
        return;
      }

       // set latitude, longitude and zoom
      this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
      this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
      this.zoom = 12;
    });
  });
});
}

 onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
var data = form.value;
let formData: FormData = new FormData();
// debugger;

formData.append('logo', this.imageFile, this.imageFile.name);
formData.append('name', data.name1);
formData.append('vision', data.vision);
formData.append('mission', data.mission);
formData.append('address', data.address);
formData.append('latitude', this.latitude);
formData.append('longitude', this.longitude);
// console.log('aaa' + data.districts);
formData.append('district_id', this.district_id);
// formData.append('school_id', 1);
formData.append('emails[0][title]', data.title);
formData.append('emails[0][email]', data.email);
formData.append('numbers[0][title]', data.numbertitle);
formData.append('numbers[0][number]', data.number);
formData.append('schoolyears[0][start_date]', data.start_date);
formData.append('schoolyears[0][end_date]', data.end_date );
formData.append( 'schooltypes[0][type_id]', this.type_id );

this._http.post(this.url, formData)
  .subscribe(response => {
    // debugger;
    console.log(response);
  }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

}
```

I just copied the needed part for the map but if you need any other code just comment and i will paste.

Second question:

How can i change the Longitudes and Latitudes variables to a dynamic value put by the user when he enters a location in the auto complete input part or when he moves the marker, just to be able to post the right coordinates chosen by the user to the web service API.

Feel free to open the web service and test if you want, any other thing inside the form is working perfectly, i need only the coordinates thing.

Comment: Map is not showing means your map placed area is empty?

Comment: No its showing the map box but greyed and no map is loading, autocomplete is working perfectly

Comment: Please check whether the map is showing after resizing the browser window.

Comment: Ok i will check and update you

Comment: Resizing is working but showing the marker only the map is still greyed :D
Google logo is showing, but no map is showing

Comment: resizing is showing the map now :D, so what is the issue?

Comment: @Ajith .........

Comment: Please see the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned 2 issues here

1.Google map invisible

You have to trigger one resize event inorder to see the map.

```
@ViewChild('map') map: AgmMap; 
resizeMap() {
this.map.triggerResize();
}
```

and call resizeMap() with timeout.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.resizeMap();
}, 1000);
```

2.Getting the cordinates

You will get the coordinates from the  `(dragEnd)` event.

```
markerMoved($event) {
  this.lat = $event.coords.lat;
  this.lng = $event.coords.lng;
}
```

Comment: Not working, do i have to call that function in the HTML?
And this is what i wrote
export class AddSchoolComponent implements OnInit {
  public latitude: number;
  public longitude: number;
  public searchControl: FormControl;
  public zoom: number;

  @ViewChild('search')
  public searchElementRef: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild(AgmMap)
  public agmMap: AgmMap;
  resizeMap() {
    this.agmMap.triggerResize();
  }

and in onOnit:
this.resizeMap();
Is this is the right way?

About the lng and lts i did it in another way but when i get it in iframe tag i get empty map :D

Comment: @MohamedWahshey Answer updated.Add on timeout when call resize().

Comment: now when i use autocomplete and choose any place, the marker shows up on the top left of the map like i have to move the map to see it clearly, but the map doesn't, still grey.

Comment: I didnt see it it was grey from the beginning but the marker wasn't showing, now the marker is shown at the top left but map still grey and if i resized it manually even for 1 px it loads, resize function is not read by the map @ajith

Comment: Ok 
 @ViewChild('search')
  public searchElementRef: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('map') map: AgmMap;
  resizeMap() {
    this.map.triggerResize();
  }

Comment: setTimeout(() => {
      this.resizeMap();
    }, 6000);
This is inside the onInit

Is this the code you wanna see?